# Getting value and key from python Collection

Tags: python-2.7

I'm struggling to get single value and key pairs from a Counter in a for loop

I have the following code:

```
test= ["test1", "test2", "apps1", "apps2", "random"]

return collections.Counter(i[:4] for i in test)
```

I get the following:
{
    "rand": 1, 
    "test": 2, 
    "apps": 2,
}

I want to know it there a way to get these values & keys based on there position if a for loop, because I'm trying to add it to a json object for an angular app.

The JSON object I want to create looks like this,

```
returnObject = []
            for i in range(len(collections.Counter(i[:4] for i in test))):
                tempObject ={
                'value': #add counter value in pos i,
                'color': 'rgb(0,19,255)',
                'label': #add counter key in pos i,
                'order': i+1,
                }
                returnObject.append(tempObject)

            print returnObject
```

Sorry I'm new to this and have tried a lot of different things, but thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `range(len)` is not the canonical way to loop over a container and not very useful for a `dict` type.

You can directly iterate over containers, e.g.:

```
counts = collections.Counter(i[:4] for i in test)
for key in counts:
    print(key, counts[key])
```

Or more directly using `.items()`:

```
counts = collections.Counter(i[:4] for i in test)
for key, value in counts.items():
    print(key, value)
```